# How to create a delegate for a property setter with its type as object

Tags: c#, object, lambda, reflection, delegates

I'm looking for a way to creating a delegate for the setter of a property without knowing the property type, say, instead of having `Action<TClass, TType>`, I would like `Action<TClass, object>`. The code which will be calling `Action<TClass, object>` will always have the right underlying type boxed as `object`. The intention is to then cache those delegates later.

Please consider the example below.

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I can set `MyProperty` as below.

```
var myClass = new MyClass<int>();
var property = typeof(MyClass<int>).GetProperty("MyProperty");
object intAsObject = 2;

//Option 1. This works, but is slow
property.SetValue(myClass, intAsObject);

//Option 2. This works, but I need to know the type of MyProperty at compile time.
var setter = (Action<MyClass<int>, int>)property.SetMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<MyClass<int>, int>));
setter(myClass, 5);

//Option 3. This does not work. It throws ArgumentException. Is it possible to achieve something like this?!
var objSetter = (Action<MyClass<int>, object>)property.SetMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<MyClass<int>, object>));
objSetter(myClass, intAsObject);
```

How to achieve Option #3? The message withing the `ArgumentException` thrown is the following:
*Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.*

Furthermore, is it possible to make it work for any `T`, i.e., `int`, `double`, `string`, `object` etc?

I have found interesting answers, such as the following, but can't find a way to achieve what I want.
[Creating a property setter delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823236/creating-a-property-setter-delegate)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It throws an ArgumentException with the following error message: "Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type." Just updated the question to include this.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16364198/12833205. I think that it can be usefull for you.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! That indeed helped me come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from Iliar Turdushev who pointed the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364198/how-to-create-a-delegate-from-a-methodinfo-when-method-signature-cannot-be-known), and thanks also to this blog post [here](https://expressiontree-tutorial.net/getter-setter-expression#:~:text=Expression%20Tree%20Tutorial%20Getter%2FSetter,to%20assign%20a%20new%20value.) I was able to come up with the below.

```
public static Delegate CreateSetter(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    ParameterExpression instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.ReflectedType, "instance");
    ParameterExpression propertyValue = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.PropertyType, "propertyValue");
    var body = Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(instance, propertyInfo.Name), propertyValue);
    return Expression.Lambda(body, instance, propertyValue).Compile();
}
```

It can then be used this way (still considering the example class in my question).

```
//The types are known for this example. But in my real scenario only an instance of PropertyInfo will be available.
var propertyInfo = typeof(MyClass<int>).GetProperty(nameof(MyClass<int>.MyProperty));

var deleg = CreateSetter(propertyInfo);
deleg.DynamicInvoke(myClass, 10);

//Prints 10 as expected
Console.WriteLine(myClass.MyProperty);
```

***Edit***: just found the below is possible too:

```
public static Action<object, object> CreateSetter(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    ParameterExpression instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "instance");
    UnaryExpression instanceExpresion = Expression.Convert(instance, propertyInfo.DeclaringType);

    ParameterExpression propertyValue = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "propertyValue");
    UnaryExpression propertyValueExpression = Expression.Convert(propertyValue, propertyInfo.PropertyType);

    var body = Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(instanceExpresion, propertyInfo.Name), propertyValueExpression);
    return Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(body, instance, propertyValue).Compile();
}
```

And used this way.

```
var action = CreateSetter(propertyInfo);
action.Invoke(myClass, 10);
```